# Jenkins/Windows - Launch TestNG suite from .bat

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, testng

Stackoverflow helped me a lot to reach that point but now I'm completely stuck, here is my problem :

I'm currently developing several tests to check a website. I code with Java in Eclipse, using testNG plugin with ReportNG for report, all of this using Windows 7 pro.

My tests work, and my report is well generated, so now I have to put it on Jenkins for my company so they will run my tests every X hours.

In order to launch my tests, I have made a file, named **Run.bat**, which runs the Java code, I tested it and it works, here is the code :

**Run.bat**

```
set classpath=blex_test_v1\bin;blex_test_v1\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG blex_test_v1\blex_test_v1.xml
```

I now try to launch the tests on Jenkins, creating a new job and configuring it with the build section :
[Run.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3keUS.png)

And this is my problem, I've tried everything (relative path, only the name of the file etc...) I always get this error :

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/jobs/blex_functional_test/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory

So I checked the Jenkins workspace but my Run.bat is in it :
[Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozSX9.png)

I have read that Jenkins is in Linux so it might cause problem with bat files, so  I tried to create a script but I didn't succeed either ..

So my question is : **How can I run my test on Jenkins using my file Run.bat** ? What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Is Jenkins running on a Windows or a Unix machine? By the looks of it it's running on Unix, thus it can not execute the `cmd` utility and you'll need to migrate to a bash script. If it's supposed to run on a Windows slave then we'll need to see the job configuration as well... **P.S.** When replying to someone's comment you can use @username so they get notified. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your welcome and quick answer @Morfic !
It is running on a Linux machine, but everyone in my team use it with Windows. So I have to write a script rather than my run.bat in order to launch my tests ? 
Is it possible to write a script that calls my run.bat ? 
Sorry if it looks dumb, I'm in internship and all of this is brand new stuff for me !

Comment: If you plan on running it under Jenkins, which in turn is running on a *nix machine, then a dedicated script that can be executed on that environment is required because to put it simple (let's not extrapolate workarounds) Win can not run Nix scripts, and Nix can't run Win scripts. You can have a Windows batch script which you use to run tests locally, and the other *nix bash script executed by Jenkins. Depending on your project setup (ant, maven, gradle, etc) a such a script may not even be necessary, but that's a secondary step for the future.

Comment: Ok I start to see where this is going ! I'll do my best to solve this, and post the answer as soon as I find it, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can add an answer :

Jenkins is installed on a Unix machine so you can't run a bat file, it has to be a bash script.

To create a bash script, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260892/launch-testng-suite-from-bash-script).

Then you have to make sure that the plugin Xvfb is installed (and works) on the computer where Jenkins is installed.

I use testNG with reportNg and it doesn't work with the last firefox version so you I use firefox v34.0.5 and this version must be installed also on the Jenkins computer.

If you want to open the report after the execution, install another plugin and configure it (report HTML or something like that)

God it took me about a week but it's good to see it working !