# Launch TestNG suite from bash script

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, jenkins, testng

I'm having trouble using my testNG suite in the Jenkins of my company. Here is the set up :

-Jenkins is installed on a Linux machine so I have to create a .sh which launch my tests.

-I code my tests under Windows, on Eclipse in Java.

-I have to use relative path in my project.

-I use my file blex_test_v1.xml to launch my tests.

I did write a batch script, it works fine without problem :

[image: Run.bat]

I now try to "convert" it into a .sh so this is what I have for the moment :

[image: test.sh]

The problem is that I always get this error :

"Error Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG"
[image: Problem]

There is about 6 or 7 posts on StackOverflow about this problem, I've read all of them, trying to change my code, rewrite it, I even uninstall all .jar files and reinstall them in my lib ... Can't see where is the problem coming from.

It can't be from the plug-in, jar files, main Class (I don't have any), my different paths or org.testng.TestNG because my .bat is working with the same meta or maybe it is different in bash script ?

For the moment I don't use Jenkins, I first try to make a runnable script and I'm reeeeally stuck here ... What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks !

PS : Here is the architecture of my project (admire my artist skills) :

[image: Archi]

EDIT: I don't use maven nor ant nor gradle, just Java in eclipse with testNG and reportNG plug-in

EDIT 2 : I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120102/bash-file-is-running-fine-in-windows-for-testng-but-it-is-not-working-in-linux-m) answer to make my bash this guy says it is working fine, but it is not for me, even if I code it with ./ (still the same error as above):

```
java -cp ./blex_test_v1/lib/*:./blex_test_v1/bin org.testng.TestNG ./blex_test_v1/blex_test_v1.xml
```

EDIT 3 : I found another typo but still got the same error :

```
export CLASSPATH=./blex_test_v1/lib/*:./blex_test_v1/bin;
java org.testng.TestNG blex_test_v1/blex_test_v1.xml
```

Note : the * makes the code look like it is commented but it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days I finally solved the problem by making a main class in my Java project calling the XML file, then create an executable jar of my project and in the end create a bash script calling this jar.

The code of my .sh is here (quite simple) :

```
java -jar Exec.jar
```